# Replace main div image with another image when other image clicked on - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I know this should be simple but just can't get this working. I have a Ruby on rails app with a property details partial that shows a large main image of a property and then some smaller thumbnails next to it. I want the user to be able to click on or maybe mouseover the thumbnail and it will display in the main image area. Here's what I have:

`_property_details.html.erb`

```
<div id="mainpic">
  <%= image_tag"http://432.mlsimages.movoto.com/0#{@property.mls.last(2)}/#{@property.mls}_0.jpg" %>
</div>
<div id="right_thumbnails">
  <% (1..@property.photo_count).each do |photo| %>

      <div class="tn">
        <%= image_tag("http://432.mlsimages.movoto.com/0#{@property.mls.last(2)}/#{@property.mls}_#{(photo - 1)}.jpg") %>
      </div>
  <% end %>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tn').on('click', function(e) {
        var img = $('.tn', {src: this.href});
        $('#mainpic').replaceWith(img);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

That jquery at the bottom is bits and pieces that I've copy pasted together, don't even know what the `e` is for, am brand new to jquery and javascript, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not incredibly familiar with RoR but it seems you have just an image and no LINK so there is no point in preventing default.

As for the changing images on click:

```
$('.tn img').on('click', function() {
    $("#mainpic img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UknBM/)

#### What is e?

`e` refers to the optional parameter `event`. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

This should works

```
$('.tn img').bind("click", function (evt) {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#mainpic img").attr("src", src);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but had to choose one and went with the simpler one, cheers